# How to implement iOS mail app multi select behavior?

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview, multi-select

I'm trying to implement a user interface scenario very similar to the stock mail app. My table is set to be single selection. I used the control-drag thing to create a push segue from my cell to another view controller. So far, all great.

Now I've added a button which sets `[self.tableView setEditing: YES animated: NO]`. Like the mail app, I want to know be able to select some of them, and then operate on them with the toolbar at the bottom. I set the *Editing* attribute to *Multiple Selection During Editing* in the storyboard editor.

What happens when I enter the edit mode, is that it indents, and I get selection graphics for free already! **BUT**... when I press the first one, it selects it and then does the push segue. Is there  an elegant way to make it push my *details* controller when it's in normal mode, but just toggle the selection state when it's in editing mode?

Having typed that... it occurs to me that I could add some indirection here. I bind the selection event to my controller, and then depending on whether the `tableView.isEditing` I either programmatically push the segue, or just toggle the selection. Is that the right way to do this? Or should I be doing something different?

Comment: Travis have you had a look at this [Apple example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when entering edit mode, set a class property BOOL editMode = YES. then in didSelectRowForIndexPath check if editMode == YES and then do nothing to select more cells, if NO start your segue.

Comment: I just used the property of the `tableView` rather than adding a new one of my own. Other than that, worked like a charm.